# combining 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays:

one of shape `(753,8,1)` denoting 8 sequential actions of a customer
and other of shape `(753,10)` denoting 10 features of a training sample.

How can I combine these two such that:

all 10 features are appended to each of the 8 sequential actions of a training sample , that is, the combined final array should have shape of `(753,8,11)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# create dummy arrays
a = np.zeros((753, 8, 1))
b = np.arange(753*10).reshape(753, 10)

# make a new axis for b and repeat the values along axis 1
c = np.repeat(b[:, np.newaxis, :], 8, axis=1)
c.shape
>>> (753, 8, 10) 

# now the first two axes of a and c have the same shape
# append the values in c to a along the last axis
result = np.append(a, c, axis=2)

result.shape
>>> (753, 8, 11)

result[0]
>>> array([[0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
           [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
           [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
           [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
           [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
           [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
           [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
           [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]])

# values from b (0-9) have been appended to a (0)
```